# Вывод ip адреса роутера python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip, python-3.6

Как известно ip роутера бывают разные: 192.168.1.1,192.168.0.1
Мне неизвестен ip адрес своего роутера как я могу его узнать и вывести с помощью print()?

(OS Windows)

Comment: Можно попросить ос показать настройки сетевых адаптеров. Ifconfig или ipconfig. А еще можно глянуть в arp таблицу. Хотя там может быть не только роутер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например вот так:

```
import netifaces

gws = netifaces.gateways()

for key in gws['default']:
    print(gws['default'][key][0])
```

можно вот так немного извратиться:

```
import netifaces

gws = netifaces.gateways()

print(list(gws['default'].items())[0][1][0])
```